# How to get a name of a css property using selenium-python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

am trying to get the following text

```
5 ⭐'s all the way! There is no better place to be!
```

using the following

```
reviews_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="review-title"]/following-sibling::')
```

from the snippet below

```
<div class="review-info">
<span class="review-title">Love!</span> 
5 ⭐'s all the way! There is no better place to be!
</div>
```

Comment: seems i cant find the string

Comment: You need to show a bit more of the html, what tag is the text actually in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have HTML like this:

```
<div class="review">
    <span class="review-title">Love!</span> 
    5 ⭐'s all the way! There is no better place to be!
</div>
<div class="review">
    <span class="review-title">Foo!</span> 
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="review">
    <span class="review-title">Bar!</span> 
    Aenean in elit id lorem aliquam
</div>
```

You can get text by removing .review-title element

```
parent_elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.review') 
for elem in parent_elems:
    review_title =  elem.find_element_by_css_selector('.review-title')
    review_title_text = review_title.text # get review title text

    # remove review_title element
    browser.execute_script("""
    var element = arguments[0];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    """, review_title)

    # this is the text
    text = elem.text

    print "%s\t %s \n-------" % (review_title_text, text)
```

Comment: what does the script do assuming we already have the review tittle text element?

Comment: the script iterates over .review elements, removes for each .review-title. when you remove .review-title element, the parent node's text becomes the text that you want to get (5 ⭐'s all the way! There is no better place to be!)

Answer (score 0):

Text is inside `body` tag, you can directly identify it using:-

```
reviews_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//body/text()')
```